# navigation+kinect+TrutleBot

Tags: navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I don't know how to do navigation on a turtlebot based on the kinect alone ??!,I'm using fuerte on ubuntu 11.10.

anyone here can help me??

Thanks..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54417/navigation+kinect+trutlebot/) by [howyda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3699/howyda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [howyda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3699/howyda/) on 2013-02-05**:
Thanks,
But navigation in tutorial need Gyro Sensor and i want to do navigation based on the kinect alone.